# How can I set a response template in API gateway to remove stack trace from Error?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using API Gateway with lambda integration. I throw below error in my code:

```
throw new Error('[400] xxxx')
```

I didn't configure any response template in API gateway so the client will receive this error:

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "[400] Customer's id 1234 doesnt exist.",
    "trace": [
        "Error: [400] Customer's id 1234 doesnt exist.",
        "    at CustomerService.<anonymous> (/var/task/src/services/base/baseService.js:71:31)",
        "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
        "    at fulfilled (/var/task/src/services/base/baseService.js:5:58)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"
    ]
}
```

what I really want them to see is `Customer's id 1234 doesnt exist.`. How can I use response template to filter out other attributes and the bracket `[400]` from `errorMessage`?

Comment: Create mapping template in API Gateway and modify the response object. Do string operations on input object and remove [400] from the string.

Comment: You cannot do response mapping templates w/ selecting `lambda as proxy` (ie that checkbox in the UI). in the case where lambda is proxy, you have to return your status code, isBase64Encoded, and all that good stuff. I dont think that is what you meant tho, but please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like the below mapping (which needs to be mapped to a 400 status code that you create). You would also need to "match" the request, maybe something like: `.*\[400\]*`:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$')) 
{
    ## Assign output properties to input properties
    "message": "$inputRoot.errorMessage"
}
```

or even more simplified:

```
{
    "message": $input.json('$.errorMessage')
}
```

Comment: Is it for every response? I only want to apply this logic in error response. Is there a way to detect if it is error?