# AWS API Gateway non proxy integration not mapped

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am using Serverless framework to generate Lambdas and the API Gateway.
Some of my functions use cognito, so i specified them as "integration: lambda" (I know this isn't mandatory, but i wanted more granular control over the returned claims).

I read that in non proxy lambda the default behavior is to always return 200, and that it can be modified. I have read about "template mapping", and also followed these two links: [question 64644447 on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64644447/how-can-i-set-a-response-template-in-api-gateway-to-remove-stack-trace-from-erro) and [API Gateway integration response setup for AWS Lambda](https://dev.to/awscommunity-asean/api-gateway-integration-response-setup-for-aws-lambda-25km). As i started following them, i noticed that "Serverless framework" already generated several responses for me; and when throwing exceptions such as `Error("[400] my bad request")` the response was as expected (status code is 400, reponse is `{"errorType": "..", "errorMessage": "[400] my bad request", ...}.`

However when trying to apply template mapping rules, nothing works, and the response stays the same. I have tried: `{"message": $input.json('$.errorMessage')}` and even `{"msg": foo"}` and to no effect. Attached are photos of lambda yaml and AWS console:

```
  http: {
    integration: "lambda",
    method: 'post',
    path: 'user/privateAPI',
    request: {
    },
    cors: true,
    authorizer: {
      name: "PrivateAuthorizer",
      type: "COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
      arn: {
        "Fn::GetAtt": ["UserPool", "Arn"],
      },
      claims: ["email"]
    }
  }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I didn't deploy my changes.
Maybe it's something obvious to various blog writers (and the official docs), but for a novice who works with Serverless Framework - this information was totally missing!

Go to Resources -> click the "Actions" button -> select "Deploy API"